# SVG <linearGradient> code keeps breaking when rendered in any browser

Tags: html, svg, linear-gradients

I've scoured all corners of the web looking for a solution to this but it seems no one else has had this issue.

Here is my current code:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="mygradient">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path id="myID" d="M 0 78.37136556477951 C 207.875 51.32892778872315 207.875 51.32892778872315 415.75 64.85014667675132 C 623.625 78.37136556477951 623.625 78.37136556477951 831.5 60.035876993171016 C 1039.375 41.70038842156255 1039.375 41.70038842156255 1247.25 64.68862384088634 C 1455.125 87.67685926021014 1455.125 87.67685926021014 1663 60.035876993171016 L 1663 3756 L 0 3756 Z" fill="url(#mygradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Whenever any browser tries to render this, the `<linearGradient>` breaks completely. This is how it renders in browsers:

```
<lineargradient&nbsp;id="mygradient"><stop&nbsp;offset="0%"&nbsp;stop-color="red"></stop&nbsp;offset="0%"&nbsp;stop-color="red"><stop&nbsp;offset="100%" stop-color="yellow"></stop&nbsp;offset="100%"></lineargradient&nbsp;id="mygradient">
```

As you can see, all spaces in the `<linearGradient>` become `&nbsp;` and `<linearGradient>` becomes `<lineargradient>`.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: using wordpress by any chance?

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope, building my site from scratch

Comment: this code is valid - there must be something happening elsewhere that's breaking this

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this one out, pasted my `<linearGradient>` code snippet into a minifier which seemed to fix the issue. Don't know why but it just did.